# Is it normal for hosting company to disable sessions on server?

Tags: php, session, hosting

I have just moved over to a linux server on my shared hosting to see if it is less rubbish than a windows server on godaddy (I have been stupid enough to have paid them 12 months up front so I am stuck with those idiots now). I am now no longer able to use any kind of sessions at all.

They have got back to me saying that it is up to me to resolve the issue to get it to work... yes that is right... TO GET SESSIONS TO WORK! Excuse me if I seem a little irate but I am furious.

Can someone please inform me how I can in some way get sessions to work on an Apache server? I have never had to set this up before because it has never been a problem. As soon as I do:

```
    <?php session_start() ?>
```

... it is just coming up with about 8 lines of errors saying that:

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/var/chroot/home/content/30/10247530/tmp/sess_sgruthqkbhfms6ekcle2l0n6i5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/content/30/10247530/html/sessionthing.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/30/10247530/html/sessionthing.php:2) in /home/content/30/10247530/html/sessionthing.php on line 2

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/30/10247530/html/sessionthing.php:2) in /home/content/30/10247530/html/sessionthing.php on line 2

Warning: Unknown: open(/var/chroot/home/content/30/10247530/tmp/sess_sgruthqkbhfms6ekcle2l0n6i5, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct () in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried creating a php.ini file and I still cannot get it to work properly. I have checked the settings using phpinfo() and I genuinely do not know where to go from here.

EDIT: There are a few things appearing down the side of the page now pointing to similar problems. For some reason I did not come up with those when I did a search. One of them is even closed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11374110/session-start-errors-on-godaddy-server?rq=1

That one says that they got it resolved with Godaddy so I think I will have to go back to them and tell them to sort it out. It is not that I do not want to learn how to configure the server... it is just that sessions should just work.

Comment: What host are you using?

Comment: It is just a standard php page. That is literally just a php file with <?php session_start() ?> and those are the errors that it is coming up with. I have just had to completely remove the entire site that was on there because the whole thing was left open to the public because it was bypassing the session check! Basically one single page with the session_start().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that there are no other `<?php session_start() ?>` declared, and try set your own session temp path,

```
<?php
  if (!is_dir(session_save_path())) {
      session_save_path ('your/custom/existing/directory');
   }
 session_start();
 ?>
```

Comment: Ok - this has fixed the issue so thank you very much. I really do not think this should be necessary though. It should not have to be set because it should be working by default. When I first tried your code I was putting in the complete path but I have now looked at someone else's post and got the idea to just use the relative address. The relative address works fine and the code works. Unfortunately I have just removed one of my domains from the hosting account in order to get hosting with another company. Looks like I will have to put it back now!

Comment: I will mark this as answered because it is a fix for the problem but I really think that it should be unnecessary with standard hosting accounts. I think it should be a default setting for PHP. Nearly everyone who uses PHP to any degree is going to using sessions...

Answer (score 1):

PHP is trying to save the session in `/var/chroot/home/content/30/10247530/tmp/`, and it can't open that directory (either because it doesn't exist or because it doesn't have write permissions to it). Investigate PHP's access to this path and I believe that you'll get your sessions working - maybe you overlooked a config variable when you migrated your code to the new server?

Comment: I didn't migrate it, they did. Should I just ask them to set up a completely new server with default settings? I have not set configurations on the server - I am just a user of the service and I am just doing standard stuff.

Comment: You could just use PHP to do a `mkdir()` somewhere and then use that for your sessions, if you can modify your PHP configuration.

Comment: I would ask them to make sure that the directory: `/var/chroot/home/content/30/10247530/tmp/` exists, and is writable by PHP - you shouldn't need to take measures as drastic as a new server to fix this.

Comment: Also - if you have access to the PHP code, just use `session_save_path()`(http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php) to set the session save path to one that *is* writable by the server.

Comment: I actually personally created a tmp file on the server myself to see if it would rectify it. I have even set that tmp file to 777 (that is complete overkill I know) but it still does exactly the same error.